# How can i call on a module in the same folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Trying a new way to keep organized. I made a file rouge.py with 1 class for one of my characters.

when i import it to main.py (my main script) and try to instantiate a Character using the Character() class it says that it is not defined

main.py:

```
import pygame
import rouge
pygame.init()

height = 500
width = 500

win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Big Quest')

running = True

ben = Character(50, 50)
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

pygame.quit()
```

rouge.py:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Character:

    def __init__(self, win, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.win = win
        self.walkcount = 0
        self.vel = 10

    def draw(self):
        self.win.blit('Mage/rougeidle_1.png', (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_presssed()

        if key == 'K_a':
            self.x -= self.vel
        if key == 'K_d':
            self.x += self.vel
        if key == 'K_w':
            self.y -= self.vel
        if key == 'K_s':
            self.y += self.vel
```

They are both in the same file. I don't understand why this doesn't work. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the file.
So in your current code it would be called as such

```
rouge.Character()
```

However, I would suggest to change the import and leave the code how it is.
The import should be.

```
from rouge import Character
```

Comment: what if i had some variables in the rouge.py file that i wanted to transfer over as well. or should that be done in the main script?

Comment: Depends on where the variables are coming from. If they are coming fr4om the main file, yes transfer them in the Character instantiation. If they are from the rouge file, you will probably want to write that file in a way that they can be imported/instantiated on run time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've imported it, you'll need to use:

```
ben = rouge.Character(50, 50)
```

or just import that class

```
from rouge import Character
```

Comment: what if i had some variables in the rouge.py file that i wanted to transfer over as well. or should that be done in the main script?

Comment: You can either import them explicitly:
```
from rouge import some_variable
```
or use them with the module path:
```
rouge.some_variable
```
Constants are probably what you want to import. Variables should probably be in your Character class so you can already access them.

Or "not recommended" `from rouge import *` which will bring in everything, but is not best practices since it can collide with your existing variable names, etc.